# Python append adds an item to every variable

Tags: python, append

I'm iterating on a list and attempting to create sublists from its items. Every time I append to a variable, the value is added to every other variable that I have defined. I've stripped down the code substantially to illustrate.

```
item = 'things.separated.by.periods'.split('.')
list1 = list2 = []

i = item.pop(0)
print i
list1.append(i)
i = item.pop(0)
print i
list2.append(i)

print(item, list1, list2)
```

Returns:

```
things
separated
(['by', 'periods'], ['things', 'separated'], ['things', 'separated'])
```

What I expected:

```
things
separated
(['by', 'periods'], ['things'], ['separated'])
```

I think this *might* by answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11975876/why-is-my-lists-append-changing-the-value-of-every-member-variable-to-the-ne/11975909#11975909), but I'm not sure how to apply this fix to my circumstances. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the line

```
list1 = list2 = []
```

This makes `list1` and `list2` refer to the exact same list, so that if you append an item to one you also append it to the other. Change it to

```
list1 = []
list2 = []
```

Comment: Wow. Thanks for the quick response, this was driving me nuts!

Answer (score 3):

```
list1 = list2 = []
```

You are setting `list1` to be *the exact same list* as `list2`. Therefore, they basically mean the **same** thing.

To fix this, try something like this:

```
list1, list2 = [], []
```