# list.append() is replacing every variable to new one

Tags: python, append

I have loop in which I edit a json object and append it to a list. But outside the loop, **the value of all old elements gets changed to the new one**
My question is similar to  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11975876/why-is-my-lists-append-changing-the-value-of-every-member-variable-to-the-ne) one here, but I still cant find a solution to my problem.

This is my Code:

```
json_data = open(filepath).read()
data = json.loads(json_data)
dataNew=[]

#opening file to write json  
with open(filepath2, 'w') as outfile:
for i in range(50):
    random_index_IntentNames = randint(0,len(intent_names)-1)
    random_index_SessionIds = randint(0,len(session_id)-1)
    timestamp = strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", gmtime())
    data["result"]["metadata"]["intentName"] = intent_names[random_index_IntentNames]
    data["sessionId"]=session_id[random_index_SessionIds]
    data["timestamp"] = timestamp
    dataNew.append(data)
json.dump(dataNew, outfile, indent=2)
```

Comment: `data` is a dictionary object. You're appending references to the same object each time, so if you change the dict then the change will be reflected throughout the list (every entry in your list is pointing to the same, single, dictionary). You need to append deep copies of the dict so that they aren't the same object in memory. That's basically what the answer you linked to is saying.

Comment: Hi @roganjosh. I'm a beginner to Python programming which is why I'm not exactly getting your point. If you have a solution, can you make changes to my code so that it works as per requirement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find the solution myself. I gave the assignment of "data" within the loop and it worked:

```
json_data = open(filepath).read()
dataNew=[]

#opening file to write json  
with open(filepath2, 'w') as outfile:
for i in range(50):
     random_index_IntentNames = randint(0,len(intent_names)-1)
     random_index_SessionIds = randint(0,len(session_id)-1)
     timestamp = strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", gmtime())
     data = json.loads(json_data)
     data["result"]["metadata"]["intentName"] = intent_names[random_index_IntentNames]
     data["sessionId"]=session_id[random_index_SessionIds]
     data["timestamp"] = timestamp
     dataNew.append(data)
json.dump(dataNew, outfile, indent=2)
```

Answer (score 5):

Every item in your list is just a reference to a single object in memory. Similar to what was posted in your linked answer, you need to append copies of the dict.

```
import copy

my_list = []

a = {1: 2, 3: 4}
b = a # Referencing the same object
c = copy.copy(a) # Creating a different object

my_list.append(a)
my_list.append(b)
my_list.append(c)

a[1] = 'hi' # Modify the dict, which will change both a and b, but not c

print my_list
```

You might be interested in [Is Python call-by-value or call-by-reference? Neither.](https://jeffknupp.com/blog/2012/11/13/is-python-callbyvalue-or-callbyreference-neither/) for further reading.

Comment: I have used both copy and deepcopy, but still, doesn't work

Comment: @TonyMathew it's hard to say what the issue is. My example above should be representative of what we can see in your code. If making a copy on each iteration doesn't work then you will need to provide a repeatable example that we can run locally.

Answer (score 2):

`data` is a dict, which means it's [mutable](https://codehabitude.com/2013/12/24/python-objects-mutable-vs-immutable/) and it's value is passed  by reference, you have to use [copy.deepcopy()]
(https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy) if you want to keep origin data not muted:

```
from copy import deepcopy
json_data = open(filepath).read()
data = json.loads(json_data)
dataNew=[]

#opening file to write json  
with open(filepath2, 'w') as outfile:
for i in range(50):
    random_index_IntentNames = randint(0,len(intent_names)-1)
    random_index_SessionIds = randint(0,len(session_id)-1)
    timestamp = strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", gmtime())
    # Create a shallow copy, modify it and append to new
    new_data = deepcopy(data)
    new_data["result"]["metadata"]["intentName"] = intent_names[random_index_IntentNames]
    new_data["sessionId"]=session_id[random_index_SessionIds]
    new_data["timestamp"] = timestamp
    dataNew.append(new_data)
json.dump(dataNew, outfile, indent=2)
```

**NOTE:** If `data` dosn't store mutable items you can use [dict.copy](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.copy) in order to avoid modifying origin value.

**Good Luck!**

Comment: It's still replacing the old elements :/ Can you find a solution to this?

Comment: I have used copy.deepcopy(). Even that isnt working :/

Comment: @TonyMathew I've updated my answer, it should work, however  if it doesn't work that's mean data is modified in other part of your code.